# I'm researching Test Case Management tools for my company. I'd love to hear pros and cons of your favorites and why

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, management

I'm currently researching test case management tools for my company; I'd like to give my development team visibility into what the testing status is, and also I'd like to have some accountability regarding regression testing. We are  small shop and need a tool to help manage mostly manual test cases, but eventually would like to do more functional automation.  Currently, we are looking at TestRail, QMetry, Zehpyr, and QAComplete amount others. I'm looking for some good feedback regarding these tools.  Please tell me your pros and cons and why?

Comment: I guess it's off topic to ask if you've considered not using 'test cases'? What are you trying to 'manage' with them?

Comment: I'd like to give my development team visibility into what the testing status is.  Also I'd like to have some accountability regarding regression testing.  Better ideas?!

Comment: Mindmaps, lo-fi test radiators can show more than 'test case count'. What do you mean 'accountability'?

Comment: What are mindmaps and lo-fi test radiators?   I'm always interested in learning new things.  I don't even know what those are.  I guess by accountability I mean tracking and reporting on responsibility for testing and tractability for requirement coverage.  Does that make sense?  Thanks for your advice, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Why not Testlink?

Pros:

1. Every needed function present
2. Possible to add additional fields
3. Possible to manage test-cases related to different projects, test-plans
4. Possible to manage different versions of test-cases
5. Possible to assign test-cases to tester for execution
6. Possible to connect to bug-tracking tools (e.g. mantis, JIRA)
7. Possible to connect to Selenium tests execution
8. Automatic metrics, reports
9. Free, open source

Cons:

1. Design
2. Not easy to import existing test cases (at least as it was for our team)
3. No custom report designer tool

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend TestCollab as one of the easiest Test Case Management Systems. With a user friendly interface, it brings a bouquet of features including :
TestCollab is a modern test cases management tool that offers a complete platform for your application's testing

- Supports both agile and waterfall methodologies
- Easily adaptable by any industry having QA needs
- Pricing plans for organizations of all sizes
- Easy to use and manage
- Secured with 256-bit SSL encryption
- Automated DB backups
- Ability for enterprises to setup TestCollab on their own AWS accounts
- Custom user rights management
- Unlimited projects
- Test cases management
- Test plans management with support for multiple configurations to enable logging of execution results for different environments
- Requirements management along with traceability matrix and coverage analysis and option to add and manage requirements within the tool itself
- Defects management with easier integration with popular bug trackers
- Bi-directional integration app for JIRA
- Custom fields for test cases and test plans
- Custom notifications
- Collaboration with all your team members
- Dashboard and reports to keep a hawk eye over the projects as
  they progress
- Easy migration from other Test Case Management tools with support for  CSV and Excel formats for data portability

To further explore the features at offer, visit https://testcollab.com

You can also try TestCollab for free by visiting https://testcollab.io/start_trial

*Disclaimer: I work for TestCollab*

Comment: This sounds a lot like an advertisement for the application. If you have any affiliation with the company, you need to say so. If you're simply a satisfied user, you should say that.

Answer (score 0):

I have evaluated testrail, spiratest earlier. My analysis is available in link http://sqlandsiva.blogspot.sg/2010/08/evaluating-test-case-management-tool.html
http://sqlandsiva.blogspot.com/2014/10/testrail-tcm-tool.html

Testrail I can share my learning's if any questions. Good Reading Notes I referred / collected for evaluating test case management tools

- http://sysgears.com/articles/tools-battle-spiratest-testrail-and-testlodge/
- http://www.lloydrodenconsultancy.com/files/Cheap%20and%20Free%20Tools.xls
- http://www.gerbenvanadrichem.com/quality-assurance/testcase-managementmy-favorite-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Of the tools you mentioned I have experience about Testrail.

Pros: Straightforward approach. Quick to start to use. Stores test cases well.
Cons: Less features to pick relevant test cases to re-run, no issue management. ( We wanted integrated issue management as it makes easier to see where the issues are regarding test cases and to pick test casea to be re-run )

We ended up in using Meliora Testlab and so at the moment if know this tool best. 
Pros: We use the tool to store the requirements / use cases. The test design from requirements is done really well.
User interface
Filter for picking right test cases
tags! We use tags for grouping test and issues.
Support: they have been helpful
Cons: Basic reports show what they should, but I miss HP:s dynamic reports to report ANYTHING. 
The tool has version field but not the concept of releases.

Anyway, the tools offer free trials so try them out, you will find what you need!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you ***TestLink***.
It is opensource, very easy to use and complete.
You can link it to integration server as Jenkins.
For me it is the most efficient opensource tool.
http://testlink.org/

From what i remember, you have a free plugin in Jira for test management. Unfortunately, it is not so user friendly the display is bad. It is a bit complex to use for what we expect from a test management tool.

If your need is for a big project and you have budget you can try for a HP product.

http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/application-lifecycle-management.html

Answer (score 0):

So, for full disclosure, I work for SmartBear Software and have used our product QAComplete, along with a few others (some mentioned above).

Like some have said above, it all depends on what you're doing and your budget as to what tool will work best for you.

I can speak for QAComplete and tell you that the biggest selling point for it is that its traceability feature works well and it integrates with popular bug tracking tools, source control, and test automation suites. Essentially, It is a hub for your manual and automated tests that can allow everyone working in the SDLC to access and comment.

That being said, what exactly are you looking for in a test management tool? What is most important to you?

Answer (score 0):

Zephyr as a plugin for JIRA is a good test case management tool.

It helps in creation and execution of test case cycles, cloning and interlinking of test cases, and their filtered viewing, besides facilitating attachment of screenshots to the ticket. Zephyr also facilitates reporting of test metrics via test summary, pie charts and graphs.

However, there is no facility in Zephyr to list all the test cases which are linked to the same issue. Also, it cannot handle historical reporting of test cases across successive versions.

This article effectively sums up the pros and cons of Zephyr for JIRA. [Test Management in JIRA using Zephyr](http://onpathtesting.com/test-management-in-jira-using-zephyr/).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth to check PractiTest. You can also read more about this tool here
[Alternatives to HP Quality Center for small business](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/alternatives-to-hp-quality-center-for-small-business)

Comment: Philip, could you please edit this answer to give more information - as it stands, your answer does not add much to the existing answers.

Comment: Kate, thanks for your question. I recommend PractiTest as a test management tool due to different parameters: 1. this tool allows to control the entire testing process smoothly. 2. It has great integration solutions. 3. Customizable fields, filters and metrics. 4. 24/7 support

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of free test management tool. Ignore the title, lol. It is for test management tool https://alternativeto.net/list/23274/free-and-open-source-team-collaboration-software